# Ubuntu disconnecting from wifi

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop lenovo ideapad 110 with RTL8821AE Wi-fi card. But it is always disconnecting from network.Then i have upgraded it to 17.04 but still the problem appeared.i have also tried to switching between antenaes..bt it did not solve my problem.if any one can solve my problem plz let me know..i will be happy to give any information about this..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) after such a wireless network disconnection and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem with Lenovo, although it only happens after a wake from sleep. Currently the solution I use is to restart the network manager

`sudo service network-manager restart`

I have script to run this short line in my home dir