# After disconnecting from wifi I must "killall wpa_supplicant" before I can reconnect

Tags: network-manager, wpa-supplicant

Everytime I disable wifi or lose connection to that network I must do a "killall wpa_supplicant" before I can reconnect. If I don't do that, the system keeps saying "[my-chosen-wifi-point] is disconnected, you are offline" every 30 seconds until I do the killall thing.

I have a recently (2 days ago) updated Ubuntu system.

When looking for a solution I found a similar problem here but the solutions there would not work for me well as I need to be able to occassionally dynamically change wifi access points (when I move around a bit):

[Need to restart network interfaces and kill wpa_supplicant, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209596/need-to-restart-network-interfaces-and-kill-wpa-supplicant-how-to-fix)

Additionally when I digged around in syslog, I found the following suspicious error messages: "NetworkManager  nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted". A quick Google search for this message turned out an as-of-today-unfixed 1 years old bug here (or it is unfixed according to Bugzilla):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1118446

Additionally, this issue started when once the machine with my Ubuntu crashed (ran a program with root rights that had a "poweroff" kernel call embedded in it, caused instant unclean power down, after booted up the NetworkManager/wpa_supplicant combo appeared to not recover properly and the wifi is broken like this since then).

What I would like to know is where exactly is that "dump" about whose "inconsistency" the NetworkManager is complaining so I can do a rm -[r]f on it to get rid of the problem. Or is there anything else wrong out there?

I also think the answer to the question(s) in the last paragraph could help with more questions, for example:

[Ubuntu disconnecting from wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922078/ubuntu-disconnecting-from-wifi)

Also note to myself. This answer could provide a somewhat working solution:

[How do I run a simple Zenity script after disconnecting from WiFi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235310/how-do-i-run-a-simple-zenity-script-after-disconnecting-from-wifi)

The trick is to tell the system to "killall wpa_supplicant" when network is down. But I am not sure whether it is going to work correctly (I don't want the wireless to die when I disconnect a wired connection for example). And it will not help much with my reconnect on access point change problem.

Comment: Take a look at my `net-o-matic` script: https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

Comment: Your project is missing documentation. I have no idea how to install and murky idea how to use it. While I can decipher the usage from the script itself, the installation turned out to be impossible to figure out as I even have no idea where the script belongs so I can't even ask Google what to do with it to get it running and asking it generic questions like "how to install network atomation scripts on Ubuntu" brings unhelpful results (this one for example brought instructions about how to automate Ubuntu installs). So, please, put at least installation instructions into the README.md file.

Comment: Same problem since I've changed my modem router into a Fritz box 7530. Killing wpa_supplicant works, but it's rather annoying.